# HTML calculator wont display anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

My HTML calculator won't display input or results. I would like to keep my layout and design if thats possible. I made this calculator with just HTML code. I wanted it to be basic to go up on a preexisting website. I have tried messing around with JavaScript and jQuery but I don't understand it well enough to get it running either. I have also tried some debugging softwares but they have yet to narrow down the problem.

Code for HTML calculator:

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-size: 1500px;
}

#calculator {
  width: 250px;
  height: 375px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #010012;
  background-color: #229EE2;
  background-size: 7px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #595959;
}

#display {
  margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
  padding-right: 2%;
  width: 220px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #595959;
  text-align: right;
  font: 27px bold;
  color: #1A3C67;
  background-color: #78c4ed;
}

#keys {
  width: 43px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #010012;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: italic;
  color: lightblue;
  background-color: rgb(0, 50, 68);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#keys:hover {
  background: #1998cd;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1e185e;
}

#keysC {
  width: 43px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #595959;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #1A3C67;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#keysC:hover {
  background: #7caad0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1A3C67;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Financial Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div class="fluid-container">
      <form name="Financial Calculator">
        <input type="textfield" id="display" name="ans" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="">
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <input type="reset" id="keysC" value="C">
            <input type="reset" id="keysC" value="CE">
            <input type="button" id="keysC" value="<--">
            <input type="button" id="keysC" value="%" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='%'">
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="7" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='7'">
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="8" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='8'">
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="9" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='9'">
        <input type="button" id="keysC" value="/" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='/'">
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="4" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='4'">
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="5" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='5'">
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="6" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='6'">
        <input type="button" id="keysC" value="*" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='*'">
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="1" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='1'">
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="2" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='2'">
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="3" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='3'">
        <input type="button" id="keysC" value="-" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='-'">
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="0" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='0'">
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="." onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='.'">
        <input type="button" id="keys" value="=" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value=eval(document.calculator.ans.value)">
        <input type="button" id="keysC" value="+" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value+='+'">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [HMTL id's](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) must be unique, for example `id=keys` could be `id=keys1`. [onClick](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onclick.asp) must be a function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you wrote `onClick`, but it is actually `onclick`, because it is **case sensitive** there.

Second of all, you wrote `document.calculator.ans.value`, which **does not work**. Instead, all you need there is just `ans.value` and you should be fine.

Below I have included the HTML code for your calculator to display what you want (it works)

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-size: 1500px;
}

#calculator {
  width: 250px;
  height: 375px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #010012;
  background-color: #229EE2;
  background-size: 7px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #595959;
}

#display {
  margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
  padding-right: 2%;
  width: 220px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #595959;
  text-align: right;
  font: 27px bold;
  color: #1A3C67;
  background-color: #78c4ed;
}

#keys {
  width: 43px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #010012;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: italic;
  color: lightblue;
  background-color: rgb(0, 50, 68);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#keys:hover {
  background: #1998cd;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1e185e;
}

#keysC {
  width: 43px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #595959;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #1A3C67;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#keysC:hover {
  background: #7caad0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1A3C67;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Financial Calculator</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style123.css">
    </head>

      <body>
        <div id="calculator">
        <div class="fluid-container">
          <form name="Financial Calculator">
            <input type="text" id="display" name="ans" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div>
                <input type="reset" id="keysC" value="C">
                <input type="reset" id="keysC" value="CE">
                <input type="button" id="keysC" value="<--">
                <input type="button" id="keysC" value="%" onclick="ans.value+='%'">
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="7" onclick="ans.value+='7'">
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="8" onclick="ans.value+='8'">
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="9" onclick="ans.value+='9'">
            <input type="button" id="keysC" value="/" onclick="ans.value+='/'">
            <br>
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="4" onclick="ans.value+='4'">
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="5" onclick="ans.value+='5'">
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="6" onclick="ans.value+='6'">
            <input type="button" id="keysC" value="*" onclick="ans.value+='*'">
            <br>
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="1" onclick="ans.value+='1'">
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="2" onclick="ans.value+='2'">
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="3" onclick="ans.value+='3'">
            <input type="button" id="keysC" value="-" onclick="ans.value+='-'">
            <br>
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="0" onclick="ans.value+='0'">
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="." onclick="ans.value+='.'">
            <input type="button" id="keys" value="=" onclick="ans.value=eval(ans.value)">
            <input type="button" id="keysC" value="+" onclick="ans.value+='+'">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[An HTML `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) have to be unique, therefor you cannot have multiple inputs with the `id="key"`. You can easily switch all of the `id` tags to [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) tags. Don't forget the css selectors!

[onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) (notice all lowercase) has to be a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions). An easy way to do this would be to declare one using a `<script>` tag and then call the function in the onclick tag of the button.

ex:

```
<script>
  function keyOnClick(symbol) {
    document.getElementById('display').value += symbol
  }
</script>
<input type="button" class="key" value="7" onclick="keyOnCick(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple Calculator

```css
#calc
{
width:300px;height:250px;background-color: pink; color: black;
}
#btn
{
width:100%;height:40px;font-size:20px;width: 40px;background-color: blue; padding-right: 10px
}
```

```html
form Name="calc">
<table id="calc" border=2>
<tr>
<td colspan=5><input style="width:300px; height: 40px; font-size: 20px " name="display" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" type="text"></td>
<td style="display:none"><input name="M" type="number"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="MC" OnClick="calc.M.value=''"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="0" OnClick="calc.display.value+='0'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="1" OnClick="calc.display.value+='1'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="2" OnClick="calc.display.value+='2'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="+" OnClick="calc.display.value+='+'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="MS" OnClick="calc.M.value=calc.display.value"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="3" OnClick="calc.display.value+='3'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="4" OnClick="calc.display.value+='4'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="5" OnClick="calc.display.value+='5'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="-" OnClick="calc.display.value+='-'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="MR" OnClick="calc.display.value=calc.M.value"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="6" OnClick="calc.display.value+='6'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="7" OnClick="calc.display.value+='7'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="8" OnClick="calc.display.value+='8'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="x" OnClick="calc.display.value+='*'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="M+" OnClick="calc.M.value=(Number(calc.M.value))+(Number(calc.display.value))"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="9" OnClick="calc.display.value+='9'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="±" OnClick="calc.display.value=(calc.display.value==Math.abs(calc.display.value)?-(calc.display.value):Math.abs(calc.display.value))">
</td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="=" OnClick="calc.display.value=eval(calc.display.value)"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="÷" OnClick="calc.display.value+='/'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="1/x" OnClick="calc.display.value=1/calc.display.value"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="." OnClick="calc.display.value+='.'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="x2" OnClick="calc.display.value=Math.pow(calc.display.value,2)"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="√" OnClick="calc.display.value=Math.sqrt(calc.display.value)"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="C" OnClick="calc.display.value=''"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```